# Passing Env Var w/ single quote to YAML - python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to use env var in a query within yaml but it won't grab the value.
Single quote needs to be preserved because Snowflake Query in string requires it.

yaml file is the input for a custom framework ( built on python ) that load the snowflake query and write to s3 as a parquet file.

To reuse the same query, I want to rotate different `ZIP_VAR` so I don't have to copy and paste the same query for different `ZIP_VAR`.

The yaml syntax looks like this:

```
query: "
SELECT ZIP 
FROM TABLE.NAME
WHERE ZIP = '${ZIP_VAR}'"
```

I've tried using block scalar( <, |, |- ). None of them is working :

```
query: |
SELECT ZIP 
FROM TABLE.NAME 
WHERE ZIP = '${ZIP_VAR}'
```

Am I doing any syntax incorrectly? Is there other way around this?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you doing with the YAML? What are you doing with Python? What tool are you expecting to do the env var replacement (YAML doesn't do this on its own)? Please give a more complete description of your use-case.

Comment: @flyx Just updated for more description. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: According to the question the "yaml file is the input for a custom framework" -- is this question asking how the custom framework parses said yaml file?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Question would be on yaml syntax. How does the var being used w/ single quote in yaml to make it work? Or it's not doable at all? hope that answers your question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

YAML does not know about environment variables and it does not treat `${…}` syntax as something special. `${ZIP_VAR}` goes in, `${ZIP_VAR}` comes out, regardless of quoting.

I suggest inputting a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), e.g.:

```yaml
query: >
  SELECT ZIP 
  FROM TABLE.NAME
  WHERE ZIP = ?
args:
  - ZIP_VAR
```

and then have your custom framework fetch each arg in `args` from the environment and pass it to the DB engine.